# Why is Verification Required?

Tags: 20.04, password

My home desktop computer runs Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with German as the interface language. This morning, for maybe the first time, I've seen an unidentified modal window three times that demands a password. Because it's modal, I have not been able to take a screenshot with Ubuntu's screenshot app.

Roughly translated from memory, the message says something like, "Verification required. Your digital keyring was not automatically unlocked. Please enter the password."

Because the window does not say "Ubuntu" or any application name, I don't know who's asking or what password it's asking for. I can hit cancel and keep working, but the window keeps coming back.

Does this ring any bells with you? Any ideas what this window might be?

Comment: Your keyring is secured with your user password and unlocks automatically with your login. But if you choose automatic logon, it cannot unlock and asks for your password. 3 Options: (1) Live with it. (2) change to login with password again (3) Remove the keyring password (see link).

Comment: @Curtis Bryant  is this new behaviour that just started?  Did you change anything before this, change to automatic login or changed password or installed a program/service?

Comment: @pLumo Yes, that post about the keyring did answer my question. I didn't know what the keyring was, and now see that it is a feature of Ubuntu that stores passwords. After unlocking it, I discovered that the keyring is storing an account password.

Comment: @crip659 No, I haven't changed to automatic login. My guess is that I probably agreed to let Ubuntu store a password, and that activated the keyring. Most of the time, I try to keep passwords only in my password manager, so maybe that's why I hadn't seen the keyring before now...

Comment: Your login should usually unlock the keyring also, but I think one setting in your keyring is preventing it.  Not quite sure if it is a keyring general setting or a setting of password in keyring itself.  Think it has to do with allowing all users.

Comment: Do not think the answer is one that works for the OP.  Seahorse/passwords and keyrings is not unlocking with his login password.  This seems to be new behaviour, not how to disable password for keyrings.